# Numpy.linalg.det() returns incorrect result

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, numpy, runtime-error

Would anyone know why Numpy is returning "-2.0000000000000004" instead of "-2" for

```
>>> M = [[1,2],[3,4]]
>>> numpy.linalg.det(M)
-2.0000000000000004
```

I am using Python 3.4.2 (x64), Numpy 1.9.1 and Windows 7 x64.

Comment: Its due to [floating numbers](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/floatingpoint.html). I would not worry about it. Its rather natural.

Comment: @Marcin
In Numpy docs everything is OK - http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.det.html
numpy.linalg.det() function returns -2.0
And if compute the determinant of an array like
a=1*4-3*2
I get int value a=-2

Comment: @Natasha: Read the tutorial that Marcin linked (or the [3.x version](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html), which is almost identical). `-2.0000000000000004` and `-2` are one bit apart, so this is just meaningless rounding error.

Comment: They have probably set the printing precission to 1 or 2, e.g. `np.set_printoptions(precision=2)`. Or in Ipython: `%precision %0.2f`

Comment: Or maybe the docs were just written with Python 2.6 instead of 3.4, so they get the old not-quite-right rounding-for-printout rules instead of the newer, more accurate ones. (The old rules truncate the partially-significant digit at the end; the new rules give you the shortest decimal string that evaluates to the exact same bits.)

Comment: Now everything is clear, thanks gays! :-*

Comment: Or maybe they just have different build options, or a different platform. For example, IIRC, `linalg.det` uses LAPACK, which can be built with SIMD operations, intermediate 80-bit float operations, or neither, which will give you slightly different (sub-last-digit) rounding differences.

Answer (score 0):

Use `round` with 2nd argument as `2` (or as required)

Example:

```
M = [[1,2],[3,4]]

print (  numpy.linalg.det(M)  )          # -2.0000000000000004

print (  round(numpy.linalg.det(M),2)  ) # -2.0
```